# SPI Interface between Arduino UNO and EVK1100

Tags: arduino-uno, spi, avr, atmel-studio

I'm using Arduino Uno board as master and AVR32UC3A0512 as slave. I've written code for arduino using SPI.h library, and Atmel Studio 6.2 using spi.h. I'm sending data from arduino to atmel i.e from SPDR register in arduino to RDR register in Atmel, but the data is not getting recieved. Hence, I'm not able to read the data. I've successfully interfaced SPI between two arduino boards and I'm using the same Arduino Master code while interfacing it with slave EVK. I've also set the baud rate same, I'm not sure what the problem might be. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Please edit your question to include code, preferably compilable/runnable code that is minimal and exhibits the problem.   That may allow someone with comparable boards to help debug the problem. [To format the code here, highlight it then click the code icon above the edit box, or press F4 iirc]  Also show a wiring diagram or table or a photo of setup

Comment: As you have not responded to the request to post the problem code, I am going to close this question as "unclear what you are asking". We can't tell you why code - *which we cannot see* - doesn't work. Particularly without details about the connections. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Feel free to edit the question with new information. Thanks for your understanding and cooperation!